In Django ORM log all quaryes in one transaction
I would like to log all SQL statements in one transaction.
I would like to distinguish between
def test_function_1():

    all = MyObject(id__in=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    for i in all:
        a = i.id
        b = i.ref1.id 
        c = i.ref2.id

def test_function_2():
        all = MyObject(id__in=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).prefetch_related('ref1', 'ref2')
    for i in all:
        a = i.id
        b = i.ref1.id 
        c = i.ref2.id

So in the first function, I would like to get 21 separate transaction logs
But in the second function, I would like to get only 1.
The
print([query['sql'] for query in connection.queries])

does not distinguish this.
My idea is to use mock/patch to tap on a transaction and then pass it trough...
Something like this (but this is not working because original queryset is then not called)
def track_db_queries(func):
    original_queryset = None
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        reset_queries()  # Reset queries before executing the function
        nonlocal original_queryset

        # Patching the on_commit method of the transaction module
        with patch.object(QuerySet, '_fetch_all', side_effect=execute_with_logging) as mock_on_commit:
            print(f"Original on_commit: {transaction.on_commit}")
            original_queryset = mock_on_commit.return_value
            print(f"Original queryset: {original_queryset}")
            func(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute_with_logging():
        # Log the SQL query or any other desired action
        print("Logging executed on_commit")
        original_queryset._fetch_all()

    return wrapper

How to do this?
